# ¿Cuándo aplica: "Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipográfico."?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Mi duda concierne la pregunta siguiente: [Error en MYSQL : syntax error missing 'semicolon'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28871/error-en-mysql-syntax-error-missing-semicolon).

Siendo que el problema del OP en este caso tiene que ver simplemente con el mal uso de una coma, reporté la pregunta con un *cierre recomendado* con la razón *Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o **un error tipográfico**.*

Sin embargo, mi reporte fue rechazado. ¿Alguien pudiera explicarme por qué? ¿Estoy entendiendo mal cuándo aplica esta razón de cierre?  Y si no aplica en este caso, ¿en qué casos sí aplica?

**Edición**

Otro más con el mismo resultado: [Inconvenientes con Store Procedure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28997/inconvenientes-con-store-procedure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de revisar la pregunta. Tu reporte fue atendido por el [moderador Comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad?tab=profile) y lo rechazó. Lo que comunicas es cierto, era un error tipográfico y por ende no es algo que ayude a la comunidad, sino que ayuda puntualmente al OP. Acabo de cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias. Y que es eso de moderador Comunidad? Es un proceso automatico? Y si es así, me pudieras explicar como funciona y como decidio en este caso de rechazar el reporte?  Nuevamente, gracias.

Comment: Acabo de agregar un enlace al perfil de este usuario.

Comment: Gracias. Entonces, que tu sepas, en este caso el rechazo se debio a que la pregunta tiene votos positivos?  Y si llegara a suceder algo similar en el futuro, es correcto de llamar la atencion en una pregunta meta, o hay una mejor manera?  Porque tuve otro rechazo ahora mismo con [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5868/error-en-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-al-usar-la-opci%C3%B3n-edit-top-200), donde por el comentario del OP mismo, no es problema que se pueda reproducir, de modo que me parece que justificaba un cierre.

Comment: Al igual que en el sitio en inglés, si hay problemas con una publicación (pregunta, respuesta) o un reporte rechazado (revisión de ediciones, cierre/eliminación de preguntas o respuestas, etc) lo puedes publicar en meta y como comunidad se decidirá qué hacer.

Comment: Sobre esa pregunta, considero que sí está en el alcance del sitio, pero nuevamente puede ser una diferencia entre nuestra forma de ver las preguntas.

Comment: @Luggi: Vaya, no doy con una. Tuve otro rechazo para [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28997/inconvenientes-con-store-procedure) donde no puede haber ninguna duda que se trata de un simple error tipografico. Hay algun efecto negativo a que tenga tantos rechazos?

Comment: Esto es extraño. Consultaré más al respecto